# XSLT Simple algorithm review

Tags: xslt

I have the following `XSLT` code:

```
<xsl:if test="position() mod 7=0 or position()=last()">
    //display logic
</xsl:if>
```

which sits inside a `foreach` loop.

The issue is, if the total count is 8, and the position hits 8, then we would be computing the `display logic` for both `position 7 and position 8 sequentially`

I believe the fix is something along the lines of

```
<xsl:if test="(count(something)=1) or (position() mod 7=0) or (position()=last() and position() mod 7>=2)">
    //display logic
</xsl:if>
```

This logic would ensure that atleast 2 records occur post modulus if we are at the last record and should guarantee up to 6 records in length before rehitting the modulus. Also, if only 1 record exists we also need to run the display logic.

But im not a XSLT guru. I am not able to test that logic until later tonight so i thought id approach SO to see if i can get some answers about whether this is the correct approach.

Thanks.

Comment: It would be useful to start by specifying what you are trying to achieve, rather than by showing us code that doesn't achieve it.

Comment: I really can't understand your explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing (!) you want to do:

```
<xsl:if test="position() mod 7 = 0 and last() - position() > 1 or position() = last()">
```

This will ensure the last group has at least 2 items. If there is only one, it will be appended to the previous group, making it a group of 8 items.

If you prefer to have a group of 6 items, followed by a group of 2, then do:

```
<xsl:if test="position() mod 7 = 0 and last() - position() > 1 or position() mod 7 = 6 and last() - position() = 2 or position() = last()">
```

---

**Demo**: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6r5Gh3q